# During helm templating, get list entry which has specific value

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

In my values.yaml I have the following object:

```
configs:
  - service1:
      this: that
  - service2:
      this: thisandthat
```

It is obviousely no problem if I don't have this as list like:

```
configs:
  service1:
    this: that
  service2:
    this: thisandthat
```

But I currently like to have this as a list so the whole content of `configs` I will be overridden by a parent chart. Otherwise my test-templating value will persist.

How can I specifically access the value of 'service2.this' without knowing the exact index of the `service2` object within the list? Is this possible at all? Or am I on the wrong path?